# How to create a pointer inside a struct

Tags: c, data-structures

I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct bucket {
    unsigned int contador; 
    unsigned int * valor;
} Bucket;

typedef struct indice {
    unsigned int bs;            
    unsigned int valor;      
    unsigned int capacidade; 
    Bucket * bucket;
} Indice;

typedef struct tabela {
    unsigned int bs; 
    Indice * indice;
} Tabela;
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
tabela->indice[2].bucket = &tabela->indice[0].bucket;
```

But I get segmentation fault.

How can I get the `tabela->indice[0].bucket` address and associate to `tabela->indice[2].bucket`.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Create pointer inside struct: just like you've done.  2) Make sure that *every* pointer actually *points* to something before you use it.  Make sure you've allocated *allocated* each object - and correctly assigned the pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm probably going to get neg repped agian for attempting to answer a c question, but here goes nothing

have you tried getting rid of the `&`?

```
tabela->indice[2].bucket = tabela->indice[0].bucket;
```

Comment: I'll go easy on you, but the most likely scenario is that these pointers have not yet been initialized. We can't say for sure from the example though, so no -1 from me

Comment: @EdS. That is what I was going to say at first, but then I read the question closer, and it almost seemed like he was already able to use the 2 values.

Comment: Well, taking the address of an uninitialized pointer would not cause a segfault and is perfectly valid. The pointer itself has a valid address.  Dereferencing an invalid pointer may cause a segfault though, so that's my guess.

Comment: First Ed is totally correct, and was *very* gentle, so thank him =) You, however, are also correct. this would be the *right* way to copy that pointer value, though I question whether that itself is what the OP thinks it is doing, especially if that Bucket pointer is free'd my someone that doesn't know all those indicies are holding it.

Comment: And yes, like Whoz said, you're correct as far as how to copy the pointer.  In that case the problem may be occurring later, in which case, you nailed it.

Comment: @WhozCraig so are you saying that `tabela->indice[0].bucket;` is equivelent to `&tabela->indice[0].bucket;` or at least refers to the same value in this case?

Comment: No, he's saying you're right and they are not the same. `&tabela->indice[0].bucket;` produces a `Bucket**`, which is wrong (and should result in a warning).

Comment: Also note that the assignment results in a leak if `tabela->indice[2].bucket` was allocated dynamically.

Comment: @EdS. it also seg-faults if `tabela->indice[0]`; didn't exist in the first place  there's a whole pile of things that could have gone wrong

Comment: @SamIam: That's the pointer I was referring to, see my response.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your pointers to point to something valid.  Simply creating an instance of your struct does not do that for you.  For example:

```
Tabela t = {};  /* t is a valid, zero-initialized object, but indice is not valid */

t.indice = malloc(sizeof(Indice) * some_count);
/* now t.indice is valid */

for(int i = 0; i < some_count; ++i)
    t.indice[i].bucket = malloc(sizeof(Bucket));

/* now t.indice[0-(some_count-1)].bucket are all valid */
```

---

By the way, your pointer copy is incorrect.

```
tabela->indice[2].bucket = tabela->indice[0].bucket;
/* assuming indices 0 and 2 are valid, this now works (but leaks memory)
   note that I removed the &.  It is incorrect and produces
   a Bucket** because t.indice[n].bucket is already a pointer */
```

However, that results in a memory leak.  It's hard for me to figure out what you are actually trying to accomplish here.